# MATLAB fwrite overhead

Tags: matlab, compression, fwrite

I have a binary logical data, that I want to save to a file in least amount of space possible. When I check the data size from the MATLAB workspace it shows, 103 kb but when I save it using fwrite ubit1 it expands to 105 kb? What can I do to save it in the least possible space?

Comment: So you're worried about the the extra two kb? What OS are you using and how are you determining the sizes? What is the exact number of bytes in your logical array, and in your output file? Are there any carriage returns in your file? It would be helpful if you provided example code to illustrate what you're doing? Using `'ubit1'` with R2015a on OS X produces files that are exactly 1/8 the size of the logical array (Matlab's logicals take 1 byte (8 bits) each).

Comment: I am worried about the 2kb because, it is for a class competition and gzip compresses a txt file that i have to 105 kb and I want to show that our algorithm works better that gzip (i.e 103 kb). I have no carriage returns. I am doing length(outputBuffer)/(8*1024) to get the size of the logical array. 

Edit: we got to down to 101.10 kb but the saved file is 104 kb
OS: OS X
Matlab version: R2013b
Length of array: 828214

Comment: What do you use to report the size of the written file ? The standard OS file explorer ? If yes be aware that most of the time it is not the exact file size but rather the size occupied on the disk by the file (which can be equal or significantly larger depending on file system and other parameters). Plus these values are usually rounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overhead (or may be you meant metadata) added by the function `fwrite` in Matlab). The function is as "low level" as it comes and on a given machine it will give similar results than the equivalent low level functions in `C`, `C++` and many more languages.

To access the disk, they will all rely on even lower level functions, driven by the `filesystem` of your disk and your operating system. So between different disks, filesystems and OS you may observe small differences in the final result, but on a given system (disk/FS/OS), the Matlab `fwrite` is similar to every other language, and there are no "overhead".

---

Now to the size of data versus size of file versus size on disk:

Consider the following snippet:

```
nbits = 376 ;
A = true( nbits , 1 ) ;

fid = fopen( 'testsize.bin' , 'w' ) ;
fwrite( fid , A , 'ubit1' ) ;
fclose(fid) ;
```

This will create an array of 376 logical, then write them with the format `ubit1` onto disk.

Before we look at the file, notice that, as mentioned in Horchler comment, in Memory Matlab still uses a full byte (8 bits) for each logical (boolean).

```
>> whos A
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes
  A         376x1               376  logical
```

This is not a problem however, since when `fwrite` will write on the disk, the format `ubit1` will tell it to only use the (single) significant bit so as Horchler commented, the file will be exactly 1/8th of the size of the variable in memory...

*or will it ??*

If I just look quickly at my file explorer, ouch:
[image: explorer]

(*This is all done on a PC, windows 8, NTFS file system.*)

1KB, naaaah, this is only because the thing is not designed to display sizes smaller than that, it's just rounded.(unix/linux user may get better display but hey I'm on windows I have to deal with it).

To get better information, I have to query more details, so once I access the properties of the file, I get:
[image: fileproperties]

pfeeew. **47 bytes**. That sounds about right. Let's see `376/8=47`, yep that's perfect!

Note the "size on disk" of a whopping 4KB. Why would you need so much space to store my poor 47 bytes ? Well that has to do with the "default allocation" size of the filesystem on your disk, and it's one of these things that `fwrite` cannot do anything about for example. It is only managed by the OS/file system.

Now even if a lot of disk is being wasted, I still managed to get the information, my file is only actually 47 bytes. So success? ... not yet.

I choose 376 bits at the beginning almost at random, but also because it was a perfect multiple of 8. Now let's try to run the very same code than above, except we'll start with:

```
nbits = 377 ;
```

The code runs fine. The file still appears as 1KB in explorer but we know it's false, the property now shows:
[image: fileprop2]

`377/8 = 47.125`, not 48, so is it "rounded" by the explorer again. NO!

**The file size is actually 48 byte** (not one bit less or more). (but the useful information inside the file only occupy 47 byte and 1 bit, the last 7 bits are undetermined (or pegged to '0' may be but don't be sure).

What happened behind the scene is that `fwrite` was aggregating my bits to write by group of 8, building a full byte, then only writing the full byte on disk (or sometimes bigger groups even). It does all that behind the scene, but it has to because the filesystem (yes him again) will not let him address individual bit on the disk. The filesystem expect packets of at least a byte (or more). So when reaching the last single bit to write, `fwrite` had to pad that with 7 other bits before telling the file system to write that on disk.

I am not expert on all the flavours of filesystem, but I strongly doubt that many will allow you to address a single bit, so the minimum rounding that you should expect will always be at least a byte ... if not more.

### Summary

`fwrite` does not introduce overhead, or only the one it is forced to do so by the hardware and filesystem (in which case any other function could not do better).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. I learnt something new :)